# Why the reference of std::vector<bool> is a prvalue whereas some document says that:"std::vector::reference is to provide an l-value"?

Tags: c++, c++11

As the subject, many experienced programmers told me "the reference of std::vector is a prvalue"(**i.e. `std::vector<bool> vec; for(x&: vec)` does not compile.**). I thought and thought about it, but I still can't understand. I would be very grateful to have some help with this question.

In addition, as per the documentation(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference), which clearly says that [emphasis mine]:

> The std::vector specialization defines
>   std::vector::reference as a publicly-accessible nested class.
>   std::vector::reference proxies the behavior of references to a
>   single bit in std::vector.
>
> The primary use of **std::vector::reference is to provide an
>   l-value** that can be returned from operator[].

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I can't agree with you. Why the document clearly declare the  std::vector::reference is to provide an l-value? You see, the URL contains **"vector_bool/reference"**.

Comment: I am not responsible for the contents or specific wording of a Wiki. I don't know what that term is intended to mean. I can only tell you how the C++ language works.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you. You give a clue. I am a novice in C++11. Why is it a temporary?  I can't see such a declaration in the documentation aforementioned indeed. I would appreciate it that if you could tell me how to identify that it's a temporary.

Comment: @NicolBolas So, I still wonder why the reference of `std::vector<bool>` is a prvalue. How can you identify it?