# Why `vector<bool> v; for(auto&& e:v){e=false}` compiles（i.e. the element's value could be modified) whereas the ref of vector<bool> is a prvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why the code below compiles (i.e. the element's value could be modified) whereas the reference of `vector<bool>` is a prvalue? I would be very grateful to have some help with this question.

Here is the related code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> v(10,true);
    for (auto&& e : v)
    {
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
        e = false;  //I wonder why this expression works whereas the ref of vector<bool> is a prvalue?
    }    

    for (auto&& e : v)
    {
        std::cout << e << std::endl;  
    }    
}
```

Comment: Do you know why `v[0] = false;` compiles?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat If `v` is the type of `vector<int>` or etc,  I can understand it as their reference is lvalue. But the reference of `vector<bool>` is prvalue (through, I do not understand it at all, some experts told me and I recited it.). I am confused. It's amazing that I can do an assignment to a prvalue!

Comment: You keep on saying "reference" which is usually meant to be an lvalue-reference (using single `&`), but what you have is an rvalue-reference (double `&&`) which makes it a very different thing. This is probably an issue that needs a language-lawyer to answer with references to sections in the C++ specification.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Some experts told me the reference of `vector<bool>`  is prvalue. Though I  do not understand it at all and I have not found any evidence yet, as their high reputation on SO, I believe they are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vector<bool>` is special. Unlike vectors of other types, it doesn't store actual `bool`s (that would require using 1 byte per `bool`). Instead, it stores them packed as bits in an array of integers (1 bit per value; for example, it might store an array of `unsigned char` and pack 8 `bool`s as bits into a single `unsigned char`).

Because there are no actual `bool`s in the `vector<bool>`, you can't form references to them. So the operations that would normally yield references (such as dereferencing an iterator) can't do so.

> Some experts told me the reference of `vector<bool>` is prvalue. Though I do not understand it at all. But as their high bonus on SO, I believe they are right.

What they mean is that dereferencing a `vector<bool>` iterator returns a [prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue) (which simply means that it returns by value rather than by reference).

By *"reference of `vector<bool>`"* they likely meant `vector<bool>::reference` and `vector<bool>::const_reference`, which refer to the types that you get when dereferencing an iterator (regular and const respectivelty) of `vector<bool>`. Normally, for `vector<T>` (`T != bool`) they would be equal to `T &` and `const T &` respectively, but for `vector<bool>`, `const_reference` is `bool` and `reference` is some class.

The `vector<bool>::reference` class has some overloaded operators to make it *work like* a reference. In particular, it has `operator=` overloaded, so you can assign `bool`s to it. (Which sets a single specific bit of the vector to `1`.)

As for why `for (auto&& e : v)` works... `auto &&` is a *forwarding reference*. I'm not going to explain how forwarding references work (look it up!), but your loop is equivalent to `for (std::vector<bool>::reference &&e : v)` (if it wasn't a vector of `bool`, it would instead become `for (ElementType &e : v)`).

When you do `e = false;`, you invoke the overloaded `operator=` of `std::vector<bool>::reference`.

Comment: TL;DR Dereferencing an iterator and `operator[]` of `std::vector<bool>` returns an object of a proxy class ([`std::vector<bool>::reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference)), which has overloaded assignment `operator=`. This serves for setting the corresponding internally packed vector element.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you for the clarifiaction. I can understand what you mean to some degree. I have no doubt with your answer. I am just a little confused. As per the documentation(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/ **vector_bool/reference** ), which clearly says that [emphasis mine]:The std::vector specialization defines std::vector::reference as a publicly-accessible nested class. std::vector::reference proxies the behavior of references to a single bit in std::vector.The primary use of std::vector::reference is to **provide an l-value** that can be returned from operator[].

Comment: @John That sentence is quite misleading in my opinion. `operator[]` of `std::vector<bool>` returns `reference` by value. How its call-expression can by lvalue? See [this relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62296219/580083). It seems that the documentation is wrong here (even cppreference is not perfect; if you are in doubts, look to the Standard :).

Comment: @John No idea what they mean by that. Maybe they were trying to say that `vector<bool>::reference` is returned by `operator[]` instead of an lvalue reference.

Comment: @DanielLangr That question is posted by myself! :)  It's a pity that it has been closed quickly.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you for the clarification. Though I don't fully understand your posted answer .  I would go out of my way to study it.